# Обработка изображений в django. Как использовать скрипты которые работают на пк?

Tags: python, django, обработка-изображений

Продолжаю изучать django, задачу для себя ставлю написать простой сайт для редактирования изображений (чернобеление, обрезка и т.д.). Как подгружать изображения я более менее разобрался, даже какой-то интерфейс сделал. Редактор изображений я сделал, но используя tkinter и в виде файла на питоне, т.е. в формате *.py. Как мне сейчас применить его к сайту который я делаю на django??? какую технологию использовать, что и где писать ? Пожалуйста помогите документацией и примерами на эта тему.